# Get Binance Fees into Spreadsheets (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, binance

I am trying to import a table from Binance fees (https://www.binance.com/en/fee/depositFee) to Google Sheets (buy i am trying into MS Excel).

When i get data, i dont know how split files for each network type.

Now, i have data like this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.binance.com/en/fee/depositFee"; "table"; 0)
```

[image: Caputre of sheet data]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is, after importing data as you did, is to split each line as following

```
=iferror(transpose(flatten(arrayformula(transpose(split(transpose(C3:F3),char(10)))))),"")
```

You will get multiple blocks of 4 columns. And finally you can group data like this way, assuming there is a max of 4 blocks :

```
=query({query( 'raw data'!A3:V,"select A,B,G,H,I,J");query('raw data'!A3:V,"select A,B,K,L,M,N");query('raw data'!A3:V,"select A,B,O,P,Q,R");query('raw data'!A3:V,"select A,B,S,T,U,V")},"select * where Col3<>'' order by Col1")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JCjJywK9qPprynX2byvAnU7jS4S9cAYmHAfLcuyW3oQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you have lost row 13 in the process

Comment: You are right ... even if for that there is no fees. You can replace where Col3<>'' by Where Col1<>''

Comment: Thanks for put all answers in the shared spreadsheet. I have to understand slowly yours answers. Thanks again for yours answers!!!!

Comment: See tab 'PLUS' with a slight modification of Aresvik's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a solution* with a formula in one cell that works over your `importrange` data (shown in cell `H1` below):

[image]

```
=arrayformula(
{query(IFERROR(array_constrain(
{"Coin/Token","Full Name","Network","Minimum Withdrawal","Deposit fee","Withdrawal Fee";
flatten(split(rept("|"&A3:A,LEN(regexreplace($C3:$C,"[^\n]",""))+1),"|"))
,flatten(split(rept("|"&B3:B,LEN(regexreplace($C3:$C,"[^\n]",""))+1),"|"))
,flatten(split(C3:C,CHAR(10)))
,flatten(split(D3:D,CHAR(10)))
,flatten(split(E3:E,CHAR(10)))
,flatten(split(F3:F,CHAR(10)))
},
max(IF(A3:A<>"",LEN(regexreplace($C3:$C,"[^\n]",""))+1,))*COUNTA(A3:A),
6)
,),"where Col1 is not null",0)
})
```

It expands the cells in columns `C`,`D`,`E` and `F` where there are multiple items in `C`. It also repeats values from columns `A` and `B`.

Columns `D` and `F` correctly convert to numbers.

- Formula updated with [Mike Steelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15019380/mike-steelson) enhancements and [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) `LEN`/`REGEXREPLACE`.

Comment: you have lost row 13 in the process

Comment: Thank you. Amended `"where Col3 is not null"` to `"where Col1 is not null"`.

Comment: @Aresvik : your solution is the best because you are calculating the maximum row in a cell. However, there is a lack of lines at the end, because line 2 is empty. After a long study of your work, I suggest a slight modification (see in the spreadsheet shared above in the 'PLUS' tab)

Comment: Thanks Mike. That works well. @player0's `LEN`/`REGEXREPLACE` is also better: `LEN(regexreplace($C3:$C,"[^\n]",""))`, so this should replace `LEN($C3:$C)-LEN(regexreplace($C3:$C,CHAR(10),""))`

Answer (score 1):

all you need is:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY({REPT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTHTML("https://www.binance.com/en/fee/depositFee", "table", 1), 9^9, 2)&
 "×", 1+LEN(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(""&
 IMPORTHTML("https://www.binance.com/en/fee/depositFee", "table", 1),, 3), 
 "[^\n]+", ))), REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(
 IMPORTHTML("https://www.binance.com/en/fee/depositFee", "table", 1)&
 "×", "select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6", 1), "\n", "×")},,9^9)), "×"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Your cols `D` and `F` appear to be formatted as text.

Comment: @Aresvik yes, they are (on purpose - to make sure mixed dataset will not be lost by any means. query likes to make assumptions of the type of dataset (numeric/plain text) and swing towards one type nullifying the other/minor one)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is amazing your one-line solution!! I need understand slowly.. heheh